# I don't understand Bayes' rule

Tags: probability, bayesian, probability-theory

I know that Bayes' rule is in form of **P(A/B)=P(B/A)*P(A)/P(B)**
What I don't understand is, what means P(A/B) and P(B/A) ?
Regards.

Comment: Note that the answerer below (correctly) used the conventional notation for conditional probability of P(A|B), with the pipe indicating "given" in "Probability of A given B".  The slash is for division.  I'd recommend changing question to use this notation.

Comment: I think you're looking for stats.stackexchange.com. This question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post above is correct. For example, if L is the event that someone has long hair and W is the event that someone is a woman, P(L|W) is the probability of someone having long hair **given** that they are a woman.

Answer (score 3):

P(A|B) == "probability that A occurs given that B occurred"

P(B|A) == "probability that B occurs given that A occurred"

P(A) == "prior"; this expresses your knowledge about event A going in.

P(B|A) == "posterior"; what you learn during the trial.

P(B) == "normalizing factor"

Bayes theorem is the scientific method: Come in with some knowledge, get some data, refine your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

`P(A|B)` effectively means: Given space of all possible events `S`, filter those that satisfy `B` and calculate the probability of `A` in the filtered space.

Comment: Space `S` comes from space... :-) But really, I defined it to be "the space of all possible events". `P(X)` means probablity of `X`.

Answer (score 1):

P(A/B): The probability A will happen if B has already happened.

P(B/A): The probability B will happen if A has already happened.

P(A): The probability A will happen INDEPENDENTLY of B.

P(B): The probability B will happen INDEPENDENTLY of A.